# In R, is it possible for pbinom to take a noninteger x?

Tags: r, self-study

I have a homework problem that is asking: "Find the probability that x is within 1 standard deviation of the mean for binomial(n = 20, p = 0.25)".

I found ${\mu} = 5$ and ${\sigma} = 1.94$. So I need to find $P(3.06 < x < 6.94)$. In R, I did `pbinom(6.94, 20, .25) - pbinom(3.06, 20, .25)` and got 0.561.

How did R compute `pbinom` when q isn't an integer? I'm confused as to how it's possible to do this when a binomial distribution is discrete.

Comment: adding self-study tag because the question as-is is perfectly on-topic only with that tag. In this case, we can't give the answer to you. But you have to show your work/understanding! I think you're starting off with the right question.

Comment: Look at this output `> pbinom(3.5, 7, 0.4)
[1] 0.710208
> pbinom(3.0, 7, 0.4)
[1] 0.710208 ` and think about it. Also look at the definition of cumulative distribution function, which is what `pbinom` gives you.

Answer (score 9):

The function is operating correctly, using the definition of the CDF.  Consider a random variable $X$ with integer support.  For any input $x+r$ with integer part $x$ and remainder $0 \leqslant r < 1$ you should get:

$$F(x+r) \equiv \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x+r) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x) = F(x).$$

Sure enough, that is exactly what `pbinom` is doing:

```
#Check CDF values
identical(pbinom(6.94, 20, .25), pbinom(6, 20, .25))

[1] TRUE

identical(pbinom(3.06, 20, .25), pbinom(3, 20, .25))

[1] TRUE
```

You can also check that this corresponds to the output of `dbinom` (to within a small tolerance due to rounding) if you want:

```
#Check CDF values against PDF values
pbinom(6.94, 20, .25) - sum(dbinom(0:6, 20, .25))

[1] 0

pbinom(3.06, 20, .25) - sum(dbinom(0:3, 20, .25))

[1] 2.775558e-17
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. Use a normal approximation to the sampling distribution of the sample mean.
2. Round the endpoints to the "closest" integer to get a conservative interval.

You may ask the teacher for clarity if this isn't clearly an application of some methods you've already covered.

EDIT:
Though R provides output for these values, the existence of their result is somewhat of an artifact of using the gamma functional to estimate the combinatorial terms in the expression of the density function. There is but a little "window" of gamma probability around the non-integral values, and relatively steep "steps" in the CDF. Importantly these "windows" and "steep steps" don't correspond to any physical term, nor does it make any practical difference from rounding.

[image]

[image]

One can try:

```
set.seed(123)
sim <- rbinom(1e7, 20, 0.25)
mean(3.06 < sim & sim < 6.94)
mean(3 < sim & sim <= 6)
```

and find

> mean(3.06 < sim & sim < 6.94)
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4hdN.png) 0.5605642
> mean(3 < sim & sim <= 6)
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4hdN.png) 0.5605642

similarly:

```
> pbinom(6.94, 20, 0.25) - pbinom(3.06, 20, 0.25)
[1] 0.5606259
> pbinom(6, 20, 0.25) - pbinom(3, 20, 0.25)
[1] 0.5606259
```

Comment: R functions with the prefix *p* are cumulative distribution functions (CDF), which are defined for any value, even for discrete distributions. There is thus no need for an approximation or interpolation.

Comment: @cdalitz see edit to understand why the confusion about fractional values is moot

Comment: Apparently the OP has problems with understanding that *pbinom* is a CDF, and what a CDF actually is. I am afraid that discussions of the internal implementation of *pbinom* might be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @cdalitz I'm a bit puzzled why, if what you say is true, that OP seems to know how to implement the correct code, and then to ask the question: "I'm confused as to how it's possible to do this when a binomial distribution is discrete."